# How to setup web.config property from external config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I created my config

```
<section name="mySettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" />
```

I can use it for my own properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mySettings>
    <add key="Param1" value="aaa" />
    <add key="Param2" value="bbb" />
    <add key="Param3" value="" />
</mySettings>
```

But now I want to create here a new property to setup web.config property. In my case it is **maxRequestLength** form web.config system.web.

How I can do it? Is it possible?

Comment: I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But I get ConfigurationErrorsException: readonly